# Jquery .removeClass( function(index, class) ) Removes the old class that i have on the element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

i have a div with the classes like

```
<div class="orignal sub-4 top-2">
```

what i want to achieve is to replace the classes sub-4 and top-2 with sub-3 and top-1 but retain the class orignal. Also is this possible to check for the prefix of a class like sub-* or to check if certain prefixed class is applied on an element.

Comment: the values for the class are variable like 2 4 or anything depending on conditions. How can i remove those classes without specifying number just through prefix...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
$('.orignal').removeClass("sub-4 top-2").addClass('sub-3 top-1');
```

to check for the class thatstarts with sub- you could use the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('div[class*=sub-]').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
$('.orignal').removeClass().addClass('orignal sub-3 top-1');
```

And to check for 'sub-':

```
$('div[class*=sub-]').doSomethingElse
```